# Tabula broke text into unnamed columns

Tags: python, pandas, tabula, tabula-py

I'm writing a script in Python to read a PDF and convert the dataFrame to a CSV with tabula, i've tried both methods, convert_into and read_pdf, they return all the pages i call, but some of the columns are split into new columns with no name like unnamed: 0, unnamed: 1 ... and have the missing fragments of the original column.

```
page = t.read_pdf(path,stream=True, encoding="UTF-8", pages=paginas, multiple_tables=True, guess=True,format="pdf")
        df = pd.DataFrame([])
        for i in range(len(page)):
                page[i] = pd.DataFrame(page[i])
                df = pd.concat([df,page[i]])
        dataAtual = datetime.datetime.now()
        saida = destino+"/ErrNFE"+str(dataAtual)+".csv"
        df.to_csv(saida, encoding="UTF-8", sep=";")
```

[Snippet of the output on LibreOffice Calc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moGzu.png)

I used the columns attribute of dataFrame to restrict the columns on the return, which works to remove the unnamed columns but also removes the text in these columns.

```
page = t.read_pdf(path,stream=True, encoding="UTF-8", pages=paginas, multiple_tables=True, guess=True,format="pdf")
        df = pd.DataFrame([])
        for i in range(len(page)):
                page[i] = pd.DataFrame(page[i],columns=({'Campo-Seq':[1,2], 'Modelo':[1,2], 'Regra de Validação':[1,2], 'Aplic.':[1,2], 'Msg':[1,2],'Efeito':[1,2],'Descrição Erro':[1,2]}))
                df = pd.concat([df,page[i]])
        dataAtual = datetime.datetime.now()
        saida = destino+"/ErrNFE"+str(dataAtual)+".csv"
        df.to_csv(saida, encoding="UTF-8", sep=";")
```

The result looks like this:
[Snippet of the output on Calc after marking the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzlTv.png)

Comment: as I know `PDF` may have very complex structure. It can even keep every char as separated object, and keep chars in random order (and use properties `x,y` to display it in correct place on screen) - and this makes big problem to work with `PDF`. If you can get data in different format (CSV, Excel, plain text) then don't use `PDF`

Comment: Thanks @furas, but unfortunately I have a PDF and need to turn it into a CSV.